# python UDP socket check connection

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a small python console that works over UDP.
The problem I'm having is that if I abruptly disconnect from the client, the connection stays open  in netstat (because it's UDP).

I have tried implementing a `threading.Timer` in the server that asks if the connection is active, and if the client does not respond within that time, the connection closes from the server-side.

This is what I tried

```
def check_conn(sock: socket.socket):
    # sock.settimeout()
    sock.send(b"\nAwake?")
    try:
        ack = sock.recv(1024)
        ack = ack.decode("UTF-8")
        if ack.strip() == "Yea":
            pass
        else:
            sock.close()
    except:
        sock.close()


so = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
so.connect((host, port))
t = threading.Timer(10.0, check_conn, [so])
t.start()
data = so.recv(1024)
#rest of the main program
```

The problem I'm having is that when it asks for the password, two `so.recv(1024)` are open, and it does not know how to handle them (that's my guess).

Comment: one of the issues you might be having is a race condition. your thread may have sent out the `awake?` packet but your main thread got the reply, or the other way around, your main thread sent something and your heartbeat thread got the reply. you should add some sort of synchronization between the two, or even do something as primitive as adding a single character at the beginning as a header to distinguish which reply goes where

Comment: I think what you said is the main issue, @Nullman, the synchronization might solve it, will look further into it, but I don't thing the single character would work, because the server program still wouldn't know which thread to handle it.

Comment: the idea is to have a single thread control the comms and and have your other threads write and read using queues. use the "single character" as an identifier for the comm thread to which queue to push the replies

Comment: But would I be able then to run the heartbeat as a thread.timeout? I'm really new with sockets and threads and haven't used any of them extensively.. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: the heartbeat would queue up an `awake?` and listen to its incoming queue for a reply with a timeout. the comm thread will read from its queue and send it. when the comm receives a reply, it will put it in the heartbeat queue. if the heartbeat queue got something from the queue, great! if it times out then your connection is dead

Comment: So in the server I would have a `check_awake` thread, which every X seconds queues an `awake?` and then the `execute` thread, which runs the usual code. And the `main` only has to worry about launching those 2 threads, listening to the 2 queues (heartbeat and execute) and sending the message to the client, right?

Comment: kinda sorta. i would have a dedicated thread for communications with a simple function that just checks its queues and act accordingly